# My function calls are not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote code first without using functions to prototype, and of course, it worked fine:

```
$(function() {
    $(".PortfolioFade img")
        .mouseover(function() { 
            popup('PORTFOLIO');
            var src = $(this).attr("src").replace("images/paperclip.png", "images/paperclip-black.png");
            /*var src = $(this).attr("src").match(/[^\.]+/) + "-black.png";*/
            $(this).attr("src", src);
        })
        .mouseout(function() {
            ;
            /*var src = $(this).attr("src").replace("images/paperclip-black.png", "images/paperclip.png");
            $(this).attr("src", src); Look at popup.js mouseover events*/ 
        });
    });
```

However, when I expressed the same in function form, the function call didn't seem to work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   // put all your jQuery goodness in here.
   $('body').hide().fadeIn(1000);

    function ImageRollover(image_element, popup_name, original, replacement)
{
    $(element)
        .mouseover(function(){
            popup(popup_name);
            var src = $(this).attr("src").replace(original,replacement);
            $(this).attr("src",src);

        })
        .mouseout(function(){
            ;
        });
}

   ImageRollover(".Portfolio img",'PORTFOLIO',"images/paperclip.png","images/paperclip-black.png"); 
 });
```

Defining the function elsewhere didn't seem to have any effect either.

Comment: Please use a proper title that describes in a few words what your problem is. Imagine other people having the same problem but won't find your question because the title is meaningless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function is defining the first variable as `image_element`, but you're referring to it as just `element` in the code.  That's quite likely one factor to it not working.

You'll likely also encounter an issue with the keyword `this` inside your function.  It isn't referring to the same object as in the original code (which jQuery sets to the HTML element for you).  In your function, it is likely not being set to anything thus it's a link to `window`.

Comment: Heh, you were 47 seconds faster :-)

Comment: :)  I also spotted the problem with `this` inside his function after posting.

Comment: Why `this` will be to window, but not to `$(element)` (if it will be corrcet variable name there)?

Comment: Hmm I suppose changing $(this) to $(element) would be correct? (Assuming I changed image_element to element)

Comment: `this` isn't set to anything by default (well, by default it's `window` in a browser).  jQuery sets it for you so it's useful, but in a function you call directly by its name, `this` isn't set.  You can set it manually by calling your function with `.apply()` or `.call()`.

Comment: 'this' was not the issue, just saying. Thank you for your input!

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you are trying to achieve?

```
function ImageRollover(element, popup, original, replacement)
{
    $(element).mouseover(function(){
            //popup(element);
            //var src = $(this).attr("src").replace(original,replacement);
            $(this).attr("src",replacement);

        })
        .mouseout(function(){
            $(this).attr("src",original);
        });
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SqyDg/

Answer (score 2):

```
    function ImageRollover(image_element, popup_name, original, replacement)
{
    $(element)
```

Where element is defined?

May be you mean:

```
    function ImageRollover(image_element, popup_name, original, replacement)
{
    $(image_element)
```

Comment: Thanks, there were two other things that had to fixed though.